# Ошибке 500 в Spring приложении

Tags: java, spring-boot

можете помочь новичку. Никак не понимаю почему у меня не работают get методы.

```
package com.madanbekov.programsex.controller;

import com.madanbekov.programsex.dto.userDto.UserDto;
import com.madanbekov.programsex.model.User;
import com.madanbekov.programsex.service.user.UserService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    @Operation(summary = "register", description = "method register user")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody User user){
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(userService.register(user));
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @GetMapping("/get/{userId}")
    @Operation(summary = "get user", description = "get user method")
    public UserDto get(@PathVariable long userId) {
        return userService.getUser(userId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/sub/{userId}/{programId}")
    @Operation(summary = "subscribe", description = "subscribe method")
    public void subscribe(@PathVariable long userId,
                         @PathVariable long programId) {
        userService.subscribe(userId, programId);
    }
}
```

```
package com.madanbekov.programsex.service.user;

import com.madanbekov.programsex.dto.userDto.UserDto;
import com.madanbekov.programsex.dto.userDto.UserMapper;
import com.madanbekov.programsex.model.Program;
import com.madanbekov.programsex.model.User;
import com.madanbekov.programsex.repo.ProgramRepository;
import com.madanbekov.programsex.repo.UserRepository;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final ProgramRepository programRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;


    @Override
    public User register(User user) {
        if(userRepository.existsByNameAndEmail(user.getName(), user.getEmail()))
            throw new RuntimeException("User already exists");

        if(userRepository.myMethod(user.getName(), user.getEmail()) != null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Пользователь не существует");
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto getUser(long userId) {
        return userMapper.convertToDto(userRepository.getById(userId));
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(long userId, long programId) {
        User user = userMapper.convertToEntity(getUser(userId));
        Program program = programRepository.findById(programId).orElseThrow(null);
        if (user != null && program != null) {
            program.getUsers().add(user);
            programRepository.save(program);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.madanbekov.programsex.repo;

import com.madanbekov.programsex.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("select u from User u where u.id = :userId")
    User getById(@Param("userId") long userId);

    boolean existsByNameAndEmail(String name, String email);

    @Query("select u from User u where u.name = :name and u.email = :email")
    User myMethod(String name, String email);
}
```

Comment: Есть лог 500 ошибки? Добавьте его в вопрос.